# What does a pair of vertical pipes mean within a function, as related to computational complexity?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm reading [Some connections between nonuniform and uniform complexity classes](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800141.804678) and trying to understand what the vertical pipes mean within h(|x|).

> Let S be a subset of {0,1}* . Let h : N -> {0,1}* where N is the set of
> natural numbers. Define S : h = { w x : x is an element of S and w = h (|x|) } .
> Next let S be any collection of subsets of {0,1}* and let F be any
> collection of functions from N to N.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure, but  $|x|$ could be the cardinal (number of elements) of $x$.

Comment: @JeanMarie *cardinality

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify any more, outside of what wrapping a variable in vertical pipes means. Cardinality of x would make sense!

Comment: @194421 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way to interpret this is that h is a function that maps a boolean string x by its length to another boolean string w in {0,1}*.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of strings - and $x$ is a string because it’s an element of $\{0, 1\}^\star$ - the notation $|x|$ means “the length of $x$.”